# How to show outlined icons in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I need to show outlined icons in my React Native App. I'm usign react-native-elements with FontAwesome as a font.

```
          <Icon
            name="star-outline"
            type='font-awesome'
            color="#FFF"
          />
```

But it shows a (?) instead of icon. If I try with name="star" it shows the star icon filled but I need it outlined style.

I would appreciate any help you can give me.. Thanks

Comment: We need to know how you're creating the Icon. Can you share the `<Icon />` component please?

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring value of attribute type wrongly Change this:

```
<Icon
            name="star-outline"
            type='font-awesome'
            color="#FFF"
          />
```

to

```
      <Icon
        name="star-outline"
        type='FontAwesome'
        color="#FFF"
      />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

At the begging check if the Icon you are using is solid or regular in FontAwesome, then you can also pass the solid, light and brands as props to the Icon tag you are using , you can find more detail on what i am talking about on,

> https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/FONTAWESOME5.md
>   and also you can have both outlined and normal icons and use them without any 3rd party provider 
>   i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're actually importing and using `FontAwesome` from `react-native-vector-icons`.
2. The icon you're looking for is actually in the `MaterialIcons` component, not the `FontAwesome` component.
3. There is an icon called `start-o` in `FontAwesome`, which is the exact same icon as far as I can tell.

### Clarification

The `FontAwesome` component actually needs to be imported into your `Icon` component file:

`import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';`

You then need to make sure you've added the prop `type` within the `<Icon />` definition in order to use it.

Unfortunately, there is no naming convention in the `react-native-vector-icons` library, so you can't simply type `-outline` after the icon name and expect it to find the matching icon.

However, the icon you're looking for may still be available, just under a different name or a different import. I agree, it's incredibly annoying, but at least someone took the time to make Material Icons relatively compatible with React Native. You can see and search for all the icons available in this library here:

https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/